# Combing two non-linear forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, spring, non-linear-systems

Imagine a permanent magnet suspended in the air with an iron disc below it. Inbetween these a thick aluminium barrier. Attached to the disc at an angle is an air spring (or air shock). The magnet attracts the disc which hits the barrier but some of the force is absorbed by the air spring.
The equation of the force the magnet produces is non-linear as it depends on displacement. The equation for the force the air spring absorbs is also non-linear because it depends on compression.

How can I combine the two equations and any others necessary to find the force the barrier experiences?

Comment: The incomplete nature of my mathematical education should permit this comment to be superseded by many (or, possibly, even any) others, but it appears to me that the results would depend on knowledge of the electromagnetic strength of the magnet, the angle & weight of the air spring, and the barometric pressures of both the air within the spring and the air separating all of the other material objects contained in this problem, with care nevertheless being taken to exclude whatever change in the pressure would be entailed by the weight and volume of the barometer itself.

Comment: Every element in the problem would need its specifications, and, in fact, a perfect solution would require adjustments for the excruciatingly tiny variations in the gravitational and barometric variations in its setting during some interval of time, assuming that that setting would occur within the earth's atmosphere, as that atmosphere would be composed of particles known to have been stationary only in circumstances that would be very rare, if ever, extant.

Answer (score 0):

The force the barrier experiences will mainly come from the impact. In the "moment" of impact, the disc decelerates from some speed to zero.

If you were to model the "impact moment" as a zero time span, this would mean infinite acceleration, meaning an infinite force (and then the finite forces from the magnet or the air spring don't matter at all).

If this result isn't sufficient, you need to model the impact as a process with some time span, and then things become very complicated. You need to analyze how the disc and the aluminium barrier deform under pressure during the impact, need to know the geometry of the objects involved (magnet, barrier, disc) and the geometry of the impact (will the disc always hit the barrier flat, center-aligned?). So, this is far beyond a task that you can solve on e.g. one sheet of paper.